# WPF : Use different icon images as an ImageBrush?

Tags: wpf, icons, imagebrush

An Icon can contain more than one image. I want to use an icon for an ImageBrush and I want to set which image inside the icon should be use. But somehow it seems I can't do that. The brush always picks the largest image from the icon.

Is there a way to choose the image manually?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible... sorry!